# Weka java spreadsubsample filter

Tags: java, machine-learning, classification, weka, arff

I'm quite familiar with Weka as I've used the GUI.  I'm doing some classification experiments that requires the SpreadSubsample filter on both my training and testing data.

I'm learning java, and want to use the weka API to do this.  I've got to the point where I'm loading my training and testing data into Weka like so:

```
 DataSource source = new DataSource("training.arff");
 Instances trainingData = source.getDataSet();
 if (trainingData.classIndex() == -1) 
 trainingData.setClassIndex(trainingData.numAttributes() - 1);
```

and I'm getting an output.  Everything is working.

However, I have no idea how to implement a filter.  I have the training and testing.arff files already produced and need to filter them through the spreadsubsample filter before loading it into weka.

If anyone could help with a thorough explanation and answer, it'd be much appreciated.  Thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

Here some sample code:

```
SpreadSubsample ff = new SpreadSubsample();

String opt = " ";//any options you like, see documentation
String[] optArray = weka.core.Utils.splitOptions(opt);//right format for the options

ff.setOptions(optArray);
ff.setInputFormat(dataset);

Instances filteredInstances = Filter.useFilter(dataset, ff);
```

Hope it helped.